# Shape of passed values doesn't match

Tags: python, pandas, subset

Head of the dataframe

```
strike,timestamp,optionType,IV,OptPrice,volume,spot,riskFree,divYield,mdate,ttm,volatility
11500.0,2019-04-03 09:21:23.035218,call,14.4,372.05,103.0,11713.2,0.0625,0.0112,2019-04-25 00:00:00.000000,0.05916,0.201913
11500.0,2019-04-03 09:21:23.035218,put,16.49,68.1,1173.0,11713.2,0.0625,0.0112,2019-04-25 00:00:00.000000,0.05916,0.144977
11500.0,2019-04-03 09:21:28.035640,call,14.4,372.05,103.0,11713.2,0.0625,0.0112,2019-04-25 00:00:00.000000,0.05916,0.201913
11500.0,2019-04-03 09:21:28.035640,put,16.49,68.1,1173.0,11713.2,0.0625,0.0112,2019-04-25 00:00:00.000000,0.05916,0.144977
11500.0,2019-04-03 09:21:33.036651,call,14.4,372.05,103.0,11713.2,0.0625,0.0112,2019-04-25 00:00:00.000000,0.05916,0.201914
```

Can be read into a dataframe by copy pasting with the code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
def greeks(optionType, spot, strike, riskFree, ttm, vol, divYield=0):
        <do something>
        return [speed, zomma, color, ultima]

af = df.apply(lambda row: greeks(row["optionType"], row["spot"], row["strike"], row["riskFree"], row["ttm"], row["volatility"], row["divYield"]), axis=1)
```

Gives me this error:

```
Shape of passed values is (5, 4), indices imply (5, 12)
```

I tried to follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43009150/2724299) and 2nd comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27385043/2724299), but it doesn't work.

```
df['speed'], df['zomma'], df['color'], df['ultima'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: greeks(row["optionType"], row["spot"], row["strike"], row["riskFree"], row["ttm"], row["volatility"], row["divYield"]), axis=1))
```

Again I get the error message as before.

If I pass the subset of `df` having exactly same number of columns as the number of arguments of the function `greeks`, which calculates the greeks, the code works.

Like the code below:

```
xf = df.iloc[:,[0,2,6,7,8,10,11]]
ef = xf.apply(lambda row: greeks(row["optionType"], row["spot"], row["strike"], row["riskFree"], row["ttm"], row["volatility"], row["divYield"]), axis=1)
ef = pd.DataFrame(item for item in ef)
xf = pd.concat([sf, cf], axis='columns')
```

But this is a hassle . Can we make so that the function can be applied to the original dataframe without to subsetting and then reattaching back to the original dataframe

Comment: What's Creek? post a sample of your dataset and your expected output, that will be easier for people to work with

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples